# In next, when I use cache:'no-store', every time hit on api ,when I no use cache:'no-store' , there is a problem, that is every tab same data show

Tags: next.js, caching

In next, when I use `cache:'no-store'`, every time hit on api, when I don't use `cache:'no-store'`, there is a problem, that is every tab shows the same data.

```js
const fetchCompletedInternationalSeriesData = async () => {
        try {
            const completedInternationalSeriesData = await fetch(getScoreApiHeader('competitions?status=result&category=international'),{cache:'no-store'}).then((res) => res.json());//per page 300
                return completedInternationalSeriesData.response;
            } catch (error) {
                return null;
        }
    };

    const fetchCompletedWomenSeriesData = async () => {
        try {
            const  completedWomenSeriesData = await fetch(getScoreApiHeader('competitions?status=result&category=women')).then((res) => res.json());//per page 300
                return completedWomenSeriesData.response;
            } catch (error) {
                return null;
        }
    };
```

I need Data will be change every tab, but api Hit for first time.